# Send values to csv with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, export-to-csv

I have a .bat file that takes a list of options, the user selects an option and the code goes to a .csv file. The problem is that it isn't filling the cells. I have other menus that are built the same way and work, but this one won't.

```
REM Prompt for Machine Type
echo Choose Machine Type
echo 1. Fat Client
echo 2. Thin Client
echo 3. Tracker Board
echo 4. Laptop
echo 5. Dock
echo.
SET /p mt=Type option: 
if "%mt%"==1 set machinetype='Fat Client'
if "%mt%"==2 set machinetype='Thin Client'
if "%mt%"==3 set machinetype='Tracker Board'
if "%mt%"==4 set machinetype='Laptop'
if "%mt%"==5 set machinetype='Dock'

set machinetype=

FOR /F "tokens=1 delims='|'" %%A in ("%machinetype%") do SET         machinetype=%%A

echo Machine Type: %machinetype%

SET file="> %~dp0addresses.txt"

echo Machine Type: %machinetype% >> %file%

echo %machinetype%, >> hardware-audit.csv
```

Comment: `SET file="> %~dp0addresses.txt"` ?

Comment: BTW, the `delims` option provides a **SET** of characters to use as delimiters, not a **STRING**. Your delimiters will be `'` and `|`, not the string `'|'`

Comment: @Magoo It is part of a larger batch file, there are a dozen variables all getting added to it 1 cell at a time in a csv.  This way every time i run the batch it saves to the same file on a new row of the csv.  I don't fully understand most of this syntax, its all a hodpodge of snippets from a dozen forums and ive just been able to modify them all to work.  All but this one menu that is.

Comment: `if "%mt%"==1 set mach...` The match is literal. **BOTH** sides of the `==` operator need to be quoted.

Comment: That hasn't had any bearing on any of the other literals, from the other menus.  I tried it though and it still doesn't work.

Comment: So you set the machine type with the IF commands. Then you wipe it out with the `set machinetype=`. You then try read the machine type variable with the for command and just set the variable again. Makes no sense why you are doing any of this.